# No man page of program Whipper in Arch Linux

Tags: software-installation, make, man

I have installed the program `whipper` with pacman in official repository in Arch Linux to rip CD's. But the man page won't come up with `man whipper`.

Then I cloned their github:
https://github.com/whipper-team/whipper
Went into the man page folder, ran `make`, and still `man whipper` would not show the man page. I do not want to build from source. and maybe that is the problem? Anyways, I would like to keep the installation from repo and get a man page. Let me know what you think I should do!

Thanks before hand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the package from the repository to contain the man page, you need to open a bug report against the package: go to https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/whipper/ and click "Add new bug".

`man whipper` does not open the man page after you ran `make` in `man/` because `man` doesn't search the current directory for man pages. To do that, you need the `--local-file` (`-l` for short) option of `man`: `man --local-file whipper.1`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know man can be specified to use a local file that way!

Answer (score 1):

So after reading @Wieland's response, this is what I did:

Added an entry in ~/.bashrc

```
alias man-whipper='man ~/path/to/man/file'
```

In this instance, the file is the whipper.1 inside the git clone directory.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might find this useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/244809/828184